# Find the primitive function of $\int \text{arccot}(x+{1\over x})\,dx$

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I'm trying to find the primitive to this function $\int \text{arccot}(x+{1\over x})\,dx$. I have used partial integration $\int fg = Fg - \int Fg'$ to solve it but I get the wrong answer:

I substituted $t=(x+{1\over x})$ and made the math but my answer $$x\text{ arccot}\left(x+{1\over x}\right) - \arctan\left({x\over x^2+1}\right)+C$$ is not correct.

Comment: Both Maple and WA give results that involves elliptic functions, so probably there is no closed form.

Comment: @Dr.MV The question has been edited since I wrote my comment: Previously the integral was $$\int \arccos \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right) dx$$ (NB $\arccos$ in place of $\operatorname{arccot}$).

Comment: @Dr.MV Mark, no worries---I myself generally assume that edits do not change something so fundamental about a question as existence of closed-form solutions, and so have occasionally been on the other side of this sort of exchange here myself. To be clear, I would not begrudge OP the change, and for that matter, it's not obvious a priori that one of these can be handled with standard techniques and that the other admits no closed form expression. -Travis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With integration by parts, you get
$$
x\operatorname{arccot}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)
+\int x\frac{1}{1+(x+1/x)^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx
$$
and the remaining integral is, after simplifications,
$$
\int\frac{x^2-1}{x(x^4+3x^2+1)}\,dx
$$
which just takes patience. The denominator factors as
$$
x(x^2+\alpha)(x^2+\beta),
\qquad
\alpha=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\ \beta=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
and partial fractions allow us to write
$$
\frac{x^2-1}{x(x^4+3x^2+1)}=
\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+\alpha}+\frac{Dx+E}{x^2+\beta}
$$
None of the remaining steps is difficult.